# Will mortar applied to my house in 29°F weather last?

Tags: mortar

My house siding was damaged from several hail storms and instead of tearing it off because it was full sheet TX43 siding in still somewhat decent condition it was more sensible to wrap over it and use it as a base for a full mortar cover. My contractor is a Sherwin Williams registered and certified contractor. However they are doing part of the mortar cover in 29 degree temperature. Is this going to hold without cracking?

Comment: Ask if they are adding stuff to it because of the cold.  There are certain additives they can use.

Comment: So, stucco? There seems to be a general (or even code-based) requirement to keep it from freezing for at least 24 hours. Ultimately, it comes down to holding them responsible if the product fails.

Comment: Have a link-only non-answer since I don't feel like writing one just now: https://www.quikrete.com/media/newsletter/inthemix/2014/1/hot-and-cold-stucco-application.pdf

Comment: What warranty does your contract with them specify? If they guarantee it for 5+ years, you should be good to go. OTOH, They were jack hammering concrete in my dorm ages ago because they'd added antifreeze to the cement when they poured it in the middle of winter a couple of decades earlier and the antifreeze was rusting the rebar. I guess you want a warranty at least as long as you expect to live there...

Comment: Also, what does being a Sherwin Williams registered & certified contractor have to do with applying any sort of mortar/stucco coat? Unless they've expanded beyond just paint...

Comment: It's a Sherwin Williams product that is warrantied by Sherwin Williams

Comment: When is it 29 degrees? Early morning at the day's lowest, or in the middle of the day?